# Unable to debug with the same version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-debugging

I am working in WPF 2012 project. I start the exe file and starts running report. In the middle it crashes saying:

> Application has stopped working

And there were 3 options below in the error dialog.

1. check online for a solution later and close the solution.
2. close the program.
3. debug the program.

When i press Debug the program, it prompts

```
"VS Just In time debugger" 
    Possible debuggers
   1) New Instance of Ms Visual studio 2012
```

I don't have any other debuggers. when i select above option it throws an error dialog "The debugger you selected cannot be started. Would you like to choose another Yes/No". When i press Yes it opens JIT error window again with same debugger.

This project in turn points to c++ dll where the error is thrown. c++ dll is creating huge loads of xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your questions is, but

What I'm guessing is happening is that VS crashes as well.

-Do you have  Intel Parallel Studio XE installed? If so, this is a known crash, that they are fixing. It seems the only workaround is to uninstall their 'Intel Debugger Extension' 
[msvsmon.exe crashes when starting debugging](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807629/msvsmon-exe-crashes-when-starting-debugging)
[throw std::runtime_error crashes Visual Studio 2013 IDE](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807509/throw-std-runtime-error-crashes-visual-studio-2013-ide)

-if not, there are two things you can do

-- use the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Feedback Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8a5aac8-0418-4f88-9d34-bdbe2c4cfe72) to get a dump and create a Connect bug for Visual Studio (it will do these automatically; if possible please include your app and repro steps in the bug). More information on how to use the tool  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=26698

-- you can use [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) to get a dump procdump.exe -ma -e -x devenv.dmp "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
This will insure that when an unhandled exception happens in the process, causing it to crash, a dump will be grabbed automatically.

Comment: i dont have Intel  Parallel Studio XE installed in my pc. I will try to get the dump and use the feedback tool. Also we can save the dump while we get the error and we can debug that dump using windbg. Which tool will give more clarity.

Comment: If you want to look at the dump yourself - you can windbg or Visual Studio